# div element 'jumps' in my jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with the following code of mine.

If I click on the h1 element, it changes its width, which is what it's supposed to do. However, the div container the h1 element is in 'jumps' a little when clicking on the h1 element. The same thing happens if I change the h1 element to div, span, etc. The only element it works with is a button.

The weird thing, however, is when I remove the first line of my HTML code (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) and leave it empty it works just fine - the div element doesn't jump. It also works if I delete the `display: inline-block` line from the CSS, but then the heading isn't centered.

Any idea what the problem might be? Or is it a bug?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery.animate()</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            $("h1").click(function() {
                $("h1").animate({width: "1000px"}, 500);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #container {
            background: orange;
            margin: 20px;
            padding: 30px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1 {
            display: inline-block;
            background: yellow;
            width: 250px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Click here</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `overflow:hidden` property to your `h1` tag and it should work great.

The animation in jQuery adds overflow:hidden to your h1 tag for a less than a 1 sec. You can see it in Webdevelopers Tools if you use them. By default its set to auto. So when your animation run your div gets this weird "jump" animation for a short while. So its simple to add this property to your styles and it wont be jumping there.

Working demo: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/51ywny19/53/)